# Chef cookbook testing and version bumping from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

Is it good idea to bump version of cookbook when promoting it from lower environment to next available higher environment. If it is good , jenkins has to fetch cookbook from github and push it to DEV/QA.. etc based on user input ( parameter build) and run the kitchen tests in the server and publish the results via jenkins email plugin. If cookbook passed the test it version has to bump and promote to next level. Can any one help to draft correct plan how to achieve it and how to implement it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can suggest only this talk of mine: https://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/an-opensource-chef-cookbook-cicd-implementation-using-jenkins-pipelines